# Pitfalls to avoid when writing project specs

Tags: project-management, application-design

I'm currently trying to write up some software specs for a large-ish project that I'd like to bid out on oDesk (maybe 3k-6k). I have a classical education in computer science, but minimal work experience and I've never worked in a corporate environment.

I've written up 15 pages of project specs for an API that I want to run on Google App Engine. I'm finding the subtleties difficult with issues such as: where to draw the line on what to specify and what not to; how to break the project up into pieces so that if one part goes wrong, other parts can still be used; where and how to set milestones; and how to screen for a candidate who has the skills to properly implement the specs.

I asked a friend what issues I should watch out for and he said:

- Make sure specs do not have contradictory information
- Make sure specs are not unnecessarily specific because this will turn off more skilled developers

What other pitfalls and common mistakes should I look out for while drawing up project specs?

Comment: I wouldn't think an API could have too much accurate and up to date documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is important to focus on the functionality of what you want to achieve, also keep in mind the non-functional requirements as well.  Think about how you want it to perform, security considerations, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One to add to the list

- Make sure the specs are unambiguous. (Can only be interpreted one way...Hopefully)

Answer (score 2):

I think these two links will help:

On Reqs And Specs: http://www.pragmaticmarketing.com/publications/topics/02/0204sj

Painless Functional Specifications - Part 2: What's a Spec?: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000035.html